# Searching un firebase realtime database with flutter not working

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm not and expert in flutter nor firebase but I've followed some tutorials and other posts and I continua stucked.
I'm trying to search in database a field ('Avenger') and I want the name and surname of this avenger. The three items are in teh same collection.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fdnj.png)

This is my part of code calling firebase and trying to reciebe something:

```
 Stream streamQuery = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users')
                        .where('Avenger', isEqualTo: 'Hulk')
                        .snapshots();
```

But qhen I try to see something in terminal I see this:

Instance of '_Future<List<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>'

Can someone could help me?
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add a subscription to this stream.

```
StreamSubscription streamQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .where('Avenger', isEqualTo: 'Hulk')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
           print(event);
           ...
        });
```